# Reason for question beeing Downvoted?

Tags: discussion, voting

I know this is a common question asked here. But I am not understanding why my [Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741988/unmet-dependencies-while-installing-gtk-3) was downvoted. Is it because its stupid or not well written or something else.
Shouldn't there be a system for the user who asked the question to know why his question was downvoted so that he can improve his question, which should improve the overall quality of the site. 
Or is there some method to achive this?

Comment: If a user wants to comment on why they gave a downvote, they can, that's the only real system for it...

Comment: Voting, including down and close votes, is how the site works.  Learn to improve your questions and answers and down votes will happen less often, but they still happen.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/help/asking for more information regarding your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you, someone also voted to close the question as `unclear what you are asking`, this is likely the reason you were downvoted too, but I can't tell for sure, I do agree that if someone thinks the question is unclear they should really say why.

To me there is nothing wrong with the question, it is a common type of question and contains all output and errors etc.

Unfortunately, sometimes people get things wrong, spend some time in review and you will see what I mean. Also there is nothing anyone can do about a single vote but don't worrie about it, one vote is negligible.

> Shouldn't there be a system for the user who asked the question to
>   know why his question was downvoted

This is an often discussed point on meta but consensus is that users should have the right to not have to explain why they voted on a Q/A because a lot of users respond with hostility and, of course, users have the right to not have to deal with that.

Check some of these post to see the discussion on voting

[Down voting consequences](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2008/down-voting-consequences)

[Downvoting answers (or questions) without a reason?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8005/downvoting-answers-or-questions-without-a-reason?rq=1)

[Can we have a feature where downvoting is only possible if the user has left a comment or filled out a form?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2635/can-we-have-a-feature-where-downvoting-is-only-possible-if-the-user-has-left-a-c)

[Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes)

[I've just been downvoted. How should I react?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121350/ive-just-been-downvoted-how-should-i-react)

There are many more in this [Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=downvoteing%20stackexchange&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=NIfZVrLrD5fOcqT_j8gK#channel=fs&q=downvoting%20stackexchange), I hope this helps to explain the situation a bit for you, even if there is nothing we can do.

Comment: "users should have the right to not have to explain why they voted on a Q/A because a lot of users respond with hostility and, of course, users have the right to not have to deal with that." that is exactly the problem with a requirement to explain down or close votes.

Comment: "To me there is nothing wrong with the question, it is a common type of question and contains all output and errors etc." and that's the problem with this. It doesn't have all the information.

Answer (score 2):

Your question lack basic information that would allow others to answer it successfully. Check [What information do I need to solve an APT dependency issue?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/121180/41104), edit your question to add more information.

Comment: what i don't understand is what all back informatino more should i provide.Thanks for the link.

Comment: I did not vote on that question, but it is unanswerable. I just skip all questions like that. Oli gave a good answer. It is maximum what can be done.

Comment: @Pilot6 "it is unanswerable" then, why not vote to close it?

Comment: Guys I add more information but still no answers what should be my best step  @Piolt6