# Can anybody please explain to me why this question got downvoted?

Tags: discussion, downvoting

https://askubuntu.com/questions/450726/unable-to-boot-ubuntu-cloud-guest-image-in-kvm

The person who downvoted did not provide any explanation for the downvote.
All it says on the downvote is: "This question does not show any research effort, is unclear or not useful". I cannot agree with any of them. I did google for possible solution but could not find any. I don't see anything unclear, I specify step by step exactly what I did and the error output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Down voting consequences](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2008/down-voting-consequences)

Comment: The possible duplicate above speaks about downvote without comments and flag instead of downvote because of rep cost mainly. This is not the problem here. The question is about not agreeing with "This question does not show any research effort, is unclear or not useful"

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why it was downvoted, but I can tell you the first Google result for
`boot uec cloud image kvm`
is pretty thorough and resolves your issue.  By the way, the link is the [Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEC/Images)...

Comment: Thanks I actually did see see this link but did not find it relevant and still don't. The instructions refer to a downloaded tarball with the .img and some floppy loaders have is the .img file.

Comment: @Ya. yeah, but where in your question says that you saw the link or tried anything at all?

Comment: If you read the WHOLE link you would have found a second link in the first: http://alestic.com/2010/01/ec2-ebs-boot-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

> "The person who downvoted did not provide any explanation for the
>   downvote.

They don't have to. Explained: [Down voting consequences](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2008/down-voting-consequences)

> The question is about not agreeing with 'This question does not show
>   any research effort, is unclear or not useful"

You don't have to agree with it for someone to find it true.

Just concentrate on making your question better, if you found research that you thought might help put it in the question - explain where things went wrong in following something.

Maybe someone was just being silly with down-votes (we may never know)- all you can control is your question - (which you are now preventing from getting answers by your own removal over pointless rep)

Answer (score -1):

AU is linked directly on Ubuntu support page (http://www.ubuntu.com/support/community) and during installation so I can't agree with rejecting questions not showing "google effort". Google is not linked on Ubuntu support page and doesn't have a menu bar in its top with "Ubuntu" "Community" "Ask!" ... menus like the one we have here.

In my opinion, the point in asking/researching on AU (and SE in general) is that you can trust the answers and that is not the case with google results. Am I wrong and we don't want this trustable reputation here?

I think if we follow this line to its end, you can find almost ALL answers with Google search and you don't need AU at all... but AU is there and working because it provides answers that are trustable and work (if not, usually the upvote/downvote/accept system and comments correct that).

This is what a lot of users seek... Not all have time to test a dozen possible "solutions" or the knowledge to see if a solution is good or not whithout testing it or to get back to the initial state after a failed "solution" test.

Comment: These are all good reasons to remove the AU link from those places, not to lower the standards of the site. This is still part of the SE network and we still expect users to first try and help themselves. Goggling is part of that.

Comment: Not that I do not agree with you but for now the fact is the links are there and AU is receiving the visiting from them. Those things should have been considered before doing the deal, not now (or change the deal).